# Optimized search function over multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing

My site sells screws of every kind. My Postgres table looks like:

| manufacturer | material | diameter | pitch | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SCREWS INC | carbon steel | 3mm | 0.1mm | 60 |
| SCREWS R US | plastic | 9mm | 0.1" | 20 |
| BEST SCREWS | pig iron | 7mm | 0.2mm | 30 |

With about 250K records.

I want to surface a fuzzy text search across all columns, so e.g. "screws inc 3mm carbon stel 60" would return the first row above.

My current implementation - reproduced below in case there's interest - is very slow, and can bring down the database when there's too much demand.

I'm wondering if there is a quicker approach to this problem, even if it trades result quality for performance.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION search_screw(search text) RETURNS SETOF screw
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  AS $$
    with distance as (
      select id,
      -- <=> is Chebyshev distance: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/cube.html
      cube(ARRAY[0]) <=> cube(
          ARRAY(
          -- Associate each word in the search string to the field it has most affinity with
          SELECT LEAST(
            -- <<-> is contiguous trigram distance: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html
            (UNNEST(string_to_array(search, ' ')) <<-> screw.manufacturer),
            (UNNEST(string_to_array(search, ' ')) <<-> screw.material),
            (UNNEST(string_to_array(search, ' ')) <<-> screw.diameter),
            (UNNEST(string_to_array(search, ' ')) <<-> screw.pitch),
            (UNNEST(string_to_array(search, ' ')) <<-> screw.quantity)
          )
        )
      ) as distance from screw
    ) SELECT screw.*
      FROM screw
      inner join distance on screw.id = distance.id
    WHERE
      distance < 0.5
    ORDER BY
      distance ASC
    LIMIT 5 -- arbitrary
  $$;
```

I tried removing the CTE but it only made it slower.

Comment: Did you try [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX). Concatenate all the columns together into a single text search vector and search it using `plainto_tsquery`.

```
select *
from screw
where to_tsvector(
  manufacturer || ' ' || material || ' ' || diameter || ' ' || pitch || ' ' || quantity
) @@ plainto_tsquery('screws inc 3mm carbon steel 60');
```

You can index this.

```
CREATE INDEX screw_ts_idx
ON screw
USING GIN (
  to_tsvector('english', manufacturer || ' ' || material || ' ' || diameter || ' ' || pitch || ' ' || quantity)
);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ef88cf33886977902cd833277839915f).

You can also simplify the query by making this a stored column and indexing that.

```
alter table screw add column for_textsearch tsvector
  generated always as (to_tsvector('english', manufacturer || ' ' || material || ' ' || diameter || ' ' || pitch || ' ' || quantity))

create index screw_ts_idx on screw using gin(for_textsearch);

select *
from screw
where for_textsearch @@ plainto_tsquery('screws inc 3mm carbon steel 60');
```